# IOS Mapkit - load pin from mssql or mysql

Tags: ios, mapkit

i want to make iphone application with map-kit but i want to get pins cordinates and title from database ,should be mssql

is that possible to get cordinates and titles from database ?
is there a any problem for apple comfirmation this app ?
can someone show me the way how can i do it

thanks for interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible to get the coordinates from a database. The app I'm working on does it. My database is running on a server that I talk to over the internet but that doesn't matter. It shouldn't matter at all to Apple where you get your data fro.

As for showing you how to do it. Now, we won't do that. What we will do here is comment on code that you post. We won't write your code for you, but we will help you out quite a lot. Google some, build some sample apps, bot mapkit ones and database ones, then put them together. When you get stuck, come back and ask away and you'll find us pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your helpfull answer,
Ofcourse i dont want to code about that i just wondered that possible or not i see now 
thanks again